# Chronometer exibir valor superior a 60 minutos no formato MM:SS

Tags: java, android

**Olá, existe a possibilidade de um chronometer exibir mais de 60 minutos sem entrar no formato hora?**

Meu chronometer recebe dados de uma String para definir o valor inicial.

```
private long minutesAndSecondsToMilliseconds(String minutesAndSeconds){
    String[] timeParts = minutesAndSeconds.split(":");
    int minutes = Integer.parseInt(timeParts[0]);
    int seconds = Integer.parseInt(timeParts[1]);
    return (minutes * 60 + seconds) * 1000;
}
```

Porém **ao receber 80:00** minutos por exemplo, **o chronometer exibe 1:20:00**.
Existe a possibilidade dele **exibir os 80:00**?

Comment: Já tentou o método [**setFormat**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Chronometer.html#setFormat(java.lang.String))?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Por padrão o valor é apresentado no formato "MM:SS" passando ao formato "H:MM:SS" quando o minuto é maior que 59.

A classe [Chronometer](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Chronometer.html) disponibiliza o método [serFormat()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Chronometer.html#setFormat(java.lang.String)) no entanto, ao contrário do que o seu nome pode sugerir, ele não serve para alterar esse padrão.
Ele serve para compor uma string, a ser apresentada, em que uma primeira ocorrência de "%s" é substituída pelo valor actual do cronómetro, na forma  "MM:SS" ou "H:MM:SS".

Por exemplo, usar `chronometer.setFormat("Passaram %s desde o início");` irá resultar em

- se o valor é menor que 60 segundos:

  `Passaram 48:55 desde o início`
- se o valor é maior que 59 segundos:

  `Passaram 1:25:23 desde o início`

Não havendo na classe um método que faça isso de forma directa, é possível fazê-lo de forma indirecta usando um `OnChronometerTickListener` e no método `onChronometerTick()` pegar o valor actual, formatá-lo como quer e atribuí-lo ao texto do Chronometer.

```
chronometer.setOnChronometerTickListener(new Chronometer.OnChronometerTickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onChronometerTick(Chronometer chronometer) {
        long time = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - chronometer.getBase();
        String minSec = String.format("%02d:%02d",
                TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(time),
                TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(time) -
                        TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(time))
        );
        chronometer.setText(minSec);
    }
});
```

Comment: Mais uma vez MUITO OBRIGADO!!